# shell script to find all files in /etc with at least 7 hard links

Tags: shell, unix

Using standard UNIX tools (grep, awk, shell builtins, etc), I need to output any file that has at least 7 hard links in the /etc directory.
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: It's appropriate to tag for a tool if you're having a problem *with that tool* -- you actually tried to use it yourself and have behavior that isn't what you expected. If you think someone might happen to use that tool in an answer, not so much; for UNIX tools, just tag `unix` and *all* standardized tools will be considered in-scope without listing them individually.

Comment: Also, it would help to show your own work so we have more of an idea of where you're starting from (and so this doesn't come across as a plz-give-me-teh-codez question). Even just "I checked the man page for `find` and couldn't find any predicates checking hardlink count" does some level of showing-your-work.

Comment: If `/usr/foo` is a hard link to the same file that `/etc/foo` is, does that count?  eg, do all of the 7 links to the file need to exist in `/etc`?  What about subdirectories of `/etc`?   What to you mean by "output any file"?  Do you mean print the contents, or print the inode?  Or perhaps you mean print all 7 (or more) of the links.

Comment: (It would also help to know more about the *specific* UNIX platform being targeted. I provided an answer using bash and GNU find; if you don't have those, but *do* have Python, it'd be tempting to use that instead).

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...good point; I assumed "files in /etc with a link count more than 7", but the OP could mean "inodes referenced more than 7 times *from within the /etc hierarchy".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `find` doesn't have a predicate for this, so you end up needing to do your own filtering. Assuming you have the GNU version of `find`, though, it can *output* link count, even if it can't filter by it on its own:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; we need the ability to tell read to stop on a NUL.
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' link_count && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  (( link_count >= 7 )) && printf '%q\n' "$filename"
done < <(find /etc -printf '%n %p\0')
```

---

To answer some likely questions regarding the above:

- *What's with the `-printf '%n %p\0'`?*

  - `%n` prints hardlink count.
  - `%P` prints the name of the file that was found.
  - `\0` prints a NUL character -- the only character that's *guaranteed not to be part of a filename*, and which is thus safe to separate them with (filenames can have newlines inside of them, so newline-separated lists of names can be misleading!)
- *What's with the `(( link_count >= 7 ))` syntax?* - See [arithmetic expression](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) on the bash-hackers' wiki.
- *What's with the `printf '%q\n' "$filename"`?* - It prints names in a human-readable way that will escape any characters that aren't printable (tabs, whitespaces, newlines, etc) -- *and* which you can copy-and-paste into a bash prompt to refer to the same file.
- *Why a `while read` loop?* - See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- *Why `read -d ' '` and then `read -d ''`?* - The `-d` argument to `read` tells it to stop when it sees the first character of the succeeding argument. `read -d ' '` tells it to stop when it sees a space; `read -d ''` tells it to stop when it sees a NUL (as a 0-length C string has one character in it -- the NUL terminator).

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is ill-posed, and presents the misconception that there are any files at all in `/etc`.  `/etc` is a directory, and as such it *does not contain any files*.  It contains only names, which are references to files.  Perhaps a short answer to the question is as simple as:

```
ls -ila /etc | awk '$3 > 7'
```

, which will list any of the names in /etc that link to the file with 7 or more links, but there is certainly no guarantee that all of those links are themselves in /etc.  I suspect the question is intended to be worded as "list any file that has a link in /etc that has at least 7 total links", in which case I would give the answer as:

```
for i in /etc/*; do stat -c '%h %i' "$i"; done |
     awk '$1 > 7{a[$2]++} END {for (node in a) print node}'
```

Or, if you just want to list all of links that are in /etc, do:

```
for i in /etc/*; do stat  -c '%h %n' "$i"; done | awk '$1 > 7'
```

Use `find` If you want to do it recursively.